# hiqpdf - asp.net - how to amend code to capture div

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, hiqpdf

This is the C# I have downloaded for hiqpdf, but I'm not sure how to amend it so it will work with my html?  There are errors coming up om my asp.net c# sheet for textBoxUrl but I'm not sure what namespace I should be using to grab this or whether I need to replace this text?

C# code:

```
using HiQPdf;

protected void Print_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // create the HTML to PDF converter
    HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

    // select the HTML element to be converted to PDF
    htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertedHtmlElementSelector =
                                    textBoxConvertedHtmlElementSelector.Text;

    // convert URL to a PDF memory buffer
    string url = textBoxUrl.Text;

    byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(url);

    // inform the browser about the binary data format
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type",application/pdf");

    // let the browser know how to open the PDF document
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                String.Format("attachment; filename=ConvertHtmlPart.pdf;

                        size ={ 0}
    ",
        pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

    // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

    // call End() method of HTTP response 
    // to stop ASP.NET page processing
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The textBoxUrl is a TextBox control. You should replace this with  your source URL.

e.g for bbc site with "#page" selector.

```
using HiQPdf;

protected void Print_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

// create the HTML to PDF converter
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

// select the HTML element to be converted to PDF
htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertedHtmlElementSelector = "#page"                               

// convert URL to a PDF memory buffer
string url = "http://www.bbc.com/";

byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(url);

// inform the browser about the binary data format
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type",application/pdf");

// let the browser know how to open the PDF document
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            String.Format("attachment; filename=ConvertHtmlPart.pdf;

                    size ={ 0}
",
    pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

// write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

// call End() method of HTTP response 
// to stop ASP.NET page processing
 HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
```